# Localizar um trecho de um HTML

Tags: c#, html, string, parser

Recebo uma *string*, e nela contém uma HTML.

Nele está uma tabela, e suas colunas:

```
<td width="24%" valign="top" border="1" style=" 
        BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; 
        BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; 
        BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; 
        BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; 
        PADDING-LEFT: 3.5pt; 
        ">

        <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 6pt">
        NÚMERO DE INSCRIÇÃO
        </font>
        <br>

        <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 8pt">

        <b>00.000.000</b><br>

        <b>MATRIZ</b>
        </font>
        <br> 
    </td>
```

Qual melhor maneira de capturar apenas aquele código: '00.000.000'?

PS: É aquela tabela de dados do CNPJ da receita.

Comment: O melhor eu não sei mas é comum o pessoal usar alguma biblioteca externa como o [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) para fazer o parser e te entregar tudo separado em nós com confiabilidade, aí fica fácil pesquisar nos elementos. Qualquer tentativa de reinventar a roda pode produzir algum resultado mas dá trabalho e dificilmente será confiável e principalmente à prova de futuro. Também não estou dizendo que estas bibliotecas sejam à prova de falha mas já é um adianto. Fora isto será complicado, trabalhoso e pouco confiável.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O melhor eu não sei, mas é comum o pessoal usar alguma biblioteca externa como o [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) para fazer o parser e te entregar tudo separado em nós com confiabilidade, aí fica fácil pesquisar nos elementos. Está parece ser a biblioteca mais utilizada para este tipo de tarefa entre os programadores .NET.

Já vi diversas outras opções, mas não gosto de nenhuma. Nem sou um grande fã desta, mas ela é melhor que nada.

Qualquer tentativa de reinventar a roda pode produzir algum resultado mas dá trabalho e dificilmente será confiável e principalmente à prova de futuro. Fora isto será complicado, trabalhoso e pouco confiável. Também não estou dizendo que estas bibliotecas sejam à prova de falha mas já é um adianto.

De qualquer forma este código HTML é bem complicado interpretar. Se for seu seria melhor modernizá-lo, não se usa HTML desta forma mais. Se você não tem controle sobre ele entenda que o código pode mudar e qualquer algoritmo criado pode se tornar inválido e trazer resultados inesperados. Mesmo usando uma boa biblioteca para fazer o parser, sem um padrão, sem uma forma de identificar inequivocamente o elemento fica muito arriscado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

**Edição para incluir um disclaimer:** obviamente em algum momento de seu processo é feito uma coisa chamada *scraping* na página da receita. Como o Maniero falou na resposta e no comentário dele, isso não é muito confiável. Minha (incompleta) solução abaixo busca um CPF ou CNPJ em um texto qualquer, que pode conter ou não HTML junto. É só por causa dessa consideração que eu respondi da forma abaixo. Em geral, quem faz *parsing* de HTML ou não sabe o que está a fazer, ou está desesperado *#ProntoFalei*.

Se tudo que você quer é extrair um CNPJ, uma expressão regular pode funcionar. Apenas note que a expressão vai ajudar porque você não vai tratar HTML, e sim apenas extrair um número do texto.

A expressão que você está procurando é algo como:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]\\[0-9]+-[0-9]+
```

E aos que entendem de REGEX: sim, eu sei que minha expressão está um tanto preguiçosa. Eu dou um voto positivo a cada um que postar uma resposta com uma expressão mais precisa.

Explicação:

- Cada bloco `[0-9]` significa "um caractere numérico aqui";
- O `+` significa que o caractere a esquerda do `+` deve ocorrer no mínimo uma vez, mas pode ocorrer múltiplas vezes. Uma forma mais correta e eficiente de capturar um CPF ou CNPJ seria repetir o bloco numérico, tipo `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`. Deixo a seu critério fazer isso;
- A barra invertida serve para escapar certos caracteres que possuem significados especiais, de forma que seus valores literais é que serão usados (no caso, `.` e a própria barra).

Note que como há barras invertidas na expressão, você deve escapá-las também quando for colocar isso numa *string* - ou colocar uma arroba na frente da *string*. Você pode usar um código parecido com o abaixo:

```
string input; // isso deve conter o seu texto de entrada
Regex foo = new Regex(@"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]\\[0-9]+-[0-9]+");
Match m = foo.Match(input);

if (m.Success) {
    string resultado = m.Groups[0]; // Suponho um único CNPJ por entrada.
}
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Para o caso dele deve funcionar até que um dia não funcione mais :) Enfim, não há solução boa.

Comment: Bom, a ideia é capturar dados diretamente da receita através do CNPJ do cliente, se é boa ou vai funcionar para sempre não sei, mas até que esteja funcionando é um extra e diferencial para o Cliente, seguindo a solução do @bigown, funcionou corretamente, que por sinal a lib é muito boa e simples de usar, obrigado

Comment: @Rod pode ter funcionado mas não tenha como certo que vai funcionar sempre. Mas você pegou o espírito. Confie sem confiar :)

Comment: @bigown, sim, isso é, pois sempre que dependemos de algo externos, tem que ter o plano b hehe, obrigado por compartilhar, abraço.